# How can I find the intervals of the $x$ in this PDF?

Tags: probability, statistics, functions, density-function

I'm trying to find the extremes of the ranges of $x$ in order to find a valid PDF having the following form:

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x, \qquad x \in [a, \, b] \\
\frac{1}{x},\qquad x \in [b, \, c]
\end{cases}
$$

It has simmetry and it's an odd function.

Which could be the values of a, b and c?

Comment: I guess you need $\int_a^b x\, dx + \int_b^c \frac{1}{x} \, dx = 1$?

Comment: @angryavian Exactly.

Comment: If I consider the two parts of the $f(x)$ separetely, the $f(x)$ is a valid PDF when:
(1) $x \in [0, \sqrt(2)]$, when $f(x)=x$;

(2) $x \in [e^{-1/2}, e^{1/2}]$, when $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @met.91 : In MathJax (the software used here) and in LaTeX you can write $\sqrt2$ with the code `sqrt2`, but if more than one object is under the radical, as in $\sqrt{234}$ or $\sqrt{2x+1}$ you can use {curly braces} thus: `\sqrt{234}`, `\sqrt{2x+1}`. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int_a^b x\, dx + \int_b^c \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \frac{b^2} 2 - \frac{a^2} 2 + \log_e c - \log_e b
$$
Here you will want $c\ge b\ge a\ge0.$ If the value of $a$ decreases to make $\dfrac{b^2}2-\dfrac{a^2}2$ bigger, but not bigger than $1,$ then you can compensate by making $c$ smaller. You have two degrees of freedom here: once $a$ and $b$ are determined, you need to find the appropriate value of $c.$ You have
$$
\log_e c = 1 + \frac{a^2}2 - \frac{b^2} 2 + \log_e b
$$
Therefore
$$
c = \exp\left( 1 + \frac{a^2}2 - \frac{b^2} 2 + \log_e b \right).
$$

Comment: I think $a \ge 0$ is also necessary since the PDF should be positive.

Comment: @angryavian : I've added that, and also made the inequalities weak.